# How to get list of all NFT using only Swift code

Tags: mobile-wallet, ios

i'm already connect my iOS all with Wallet using SmartWalletConnect and got wallet address
How can i get list of all NFT using  https://github.com/skywinder/web3swift ?
Or how can i get list of NFT from one source ?
I know that i can use opensea Api. But i want to do it by my own